# Alphabetize words within filenames using sort?

Tags: bash, rename, sort

When reading tutorials on batch-renaming files in bash and using the `sort` command to sort file contents, I have not been able to figure out how to combine the two.

I have a directory whose contents are sorted using tags within the filename, similar to how the program [TagSpaces](https://www.tagspaces.org/) handles things. I add whatever tags I can think of to the end of the filename when I create it or download it. Here's an example:

```
Sunrise (2) #wallpaper #4k #googleimages.jpg
```

Now I want to go through all these files and rename them so the tags are sorted alphabetically, without affecting anything before or after the tags (e.g. a picture's title or file extension). So the above would become:

```
Sunrise (2) #4k #googleimages #wallpaper.jpg
```

**How do I accomplish this?** I can't even figure out how to pass a file's *name*, and not its contents, to a command like `sort`, whose output I could then perhaps pipe to `mv`.

Comment: not an answer to your question, but you should post an answer about TagSpaces in [Adding tags to files (PDFs) and process from the command-line or script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383552/adding-tags-to-files-pdfs-and-process-from-the-command-line-or-script) - it seems very relevant to that question at first glance.

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in dir_for_files/*; do
    filename=${i%%#*}
    sorted_tags=$(grep -o "#[^ .]*" <<< "$i" | sort -n | tr '\n' ' ')
    ext=${i#*.}
    echo mv "$i" "${filename}${sorted_tags% }.$ext"
done
```

**Testing:**

```
##### Before sorting #####    
$ ls -1 dir_for_files
Note (3) #textfile #notes #important.txt
Sunrise (2) #wallpaper #4k #googleimages.jpg
Sunset (2) #wallpaper #2k #images.jpg

$ ./sort_tags.sh

##### After sorting #####
$ ls -1 dir_for_files
Note (3) #important #notes #textfile.txt
Sunrise (2) #4k #googleimages #wallpaper.jpg
Sunset (2) #2k #images #wallpaper.jpg
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the perl-based `rename` (`prename` on some systems) then you could do a split + sort the tags using perl. For example, given

```
$ ls *.jpg
Sunrise (2) #wallpaper #4k #googleimages.jpg
```

then (with some ugly wrangling to remove and replace the `.jpg` suffix)

```
$ rename -v 'my @F = split / #/, substr($_,0,-4); $_ = (join " #", shift @F, sort @F) . ".jpg"' *.jpg
Sunrise (2) #wallpaper #4k #googleimages.jpg renamed as Sunrise (2) #4k #googleimages #wallpaper.jpg
```

Checking

```
$ ls *.jpg
Sunrise (2) #4k #googleimages #wallpaper.jpg
```

Probably lots of room for improvement - but I hope it gives you some idea.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n '([^#]#)(\#*)(.*)' '$1${(j: :)${(os: :)2}}$3'
```

(remove the `-n` (dry-run) if happy).

- `[^#]#`: 0 or more non-# characters (`#` is like `*` in regexps)
- `s: :` split on space
- `o`: order (sort)
- `j: :`: join with space.

So, we're splitting the part in between the first `#` (included) and last `.` (excluded) on space, sort the resulting list which we join back with space.

Recursively:

```
zmv -n '(**/)([^#]#)(\#*)(.*)' '$1$2${(j: :)${(os: :)3}}$4'
```

To allow spaces in tag names, we could split on `#` and trim trailing spaces, sort and join on `#` with:

```
zmv -n '([^#]#\#)(*)(.*)' '$1${(j: #:)${(os:#:)2}%% #}$3'
```

Add a `(#qD)` glob qualifier if you also want to process hidden files (`D`ot files) or want to process files in hidden directories.

Answer (score 2):

**Nice question!**

Here is my simple `bash` script for this:

```bsh
for file in *.jpg; do 
    afile=( ${file#*)} ); 
    echo mv "$file" "${file%%#*}$(echo $(sort<(printf "%s\n" "${afile[@]%%.*}"))).jpg";
done
```

**Explanation:**

- In `afile=( ${file#*)} );`**:** we are converting the string to an array. In this state shell is performing word splitting with spaces unless you quote the string.

  In `${file#*)}` (*cut-up-to-first-prefix*): we are stripping everything from the start of the string till first `)` seen using [`shell parameter expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) as it will result `#wallpaper #4k #googleimages.jpg`considering the `file="Sunrise (2) #wallpaper #4k #googleimages.jpg"`
- In `${file%%#*}` (*cut-up-to-last-suffix*); stripping start from end to the begging of string till last `#` seen. this will result `Sunrise (2)`
- In `${afile[@]%%.*}` (*cut-up-to-last-suffix*): same as above, stripping start from end to the begging of string (here in each indexed array) till last `.` seen. this will result `#wallpaper #4k #googleimages`, we could also use `${afile[@]%.*}` better!
- In `printf "%s\n" "${afile[@]%%.*}"`: we are printing the array elements with newlines (`[@]` used for indexed array), (why with newlines? Because we will sort them and we should split the elements in newlines)
- In `$(sort<(printf "%s\n" "${afile[@]%%.*}"))`: we are sorting the elements (or tags).
- In `$(echo $(sort<(printf "%s\n" "${afile[@]%%.*}")))`: same as above but we used extra `echo` command to gathering the sorted elements into the one linear.

  possible same also with using double `xargs` like `... |xargs -n1| sort | xargs`. 
  Please see below example to better understand this step:

  ```
  echo -e "C\n4\nB" |sort
  4
  B
  C
  echo $(echo -e "C\n4\nB" |sort)
  4 B C
  ```

Finally at the end, `mv` command is renaming the `$file` to the modified name should be.

*Ps:* remove `echo mv ...` in front of the `mv` to exit dry-run and perform actual renaming.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bit too complicated for Bash to be honest. It's not impossible, but in my opinion, you're far better off using a language made for "real" programming here. A Bash solution will likely be unmaintanable. (Not trying to insult the Bash-only solution, I think the rename-magic is pretty amazing, actually)

That said, here's a solution with Ruby. You can write it to a file and then just execute the file from within your shell, given that you have Ruby installed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
Dir.glob('*.jpg').each do |filename|
    # `name` contains the name of the file, without the tags. `tags` is an array
    # of all tags of the file.
    name, *tags = filename.split(' #')
    # if there aren't any tags, just skip the file.
    if tags.empty?
        next
    end
    # remove the trailing '.jpg' and sort all the tags
    tags.last.gsub!(/\.jpg$/,'')
    tags.sort!
    tags = [name] + tags
    # finally, move the file to the correct location with sorted tags.
    File.rename filename, "#{tags.join(' #')}.jpg"
end
```

To execute the script, simply place it in the directory where your images are in. This solution should be fairly resilient to silly image names and tags like `C#` won't cause problems. That said, be sure to make a backup before running the script. Movement operations can be just as destructive as a `rm`.