# How can I numerically sort a single line of delimited items?

Tags: sort, numeric-data

I have a line (or many lines) of numbers that are delimited by an arbitrary character. What UNIX tools can I use to sort each line's items numerically, retaining the delimiter?

Examples include:

- list of numbers; input: `10 50 23 42`; sorted: `10 23 42 50`
- IP address; input: `10.1.200.42`; sorted: `1.10.42.200`
- CSV; input: `1,100,330,42`; sorted: `1,42,100,330`
- pipe-delimited; input: `400|500|404`; sorted: `400|404|500`

Since the delimiter is arbitrary, feel free to provide (or extend) an Answer using a single-character delimiter of your choosing.

Comment: you should post it over on codegolf :)

Comment: there is a similar question also here I would like to add its link [Alphabetize words within filenames using sort?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/384291/72456)

Comment: Just a hint that `cut` supports arbitrary delimiters with its `-d` option.

Comment: Please clarify as to whether those four examples of [DSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values)s are in the same file, or are samples from four different files.

Comment: @agc , those are independent examples in order to demonstrate the arbitrary nature of the delimiter.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, also, are the numbers *naturals*, *integers*, (*i.e.* signed), or *rationals*, *et al*?

Comment: Good clarification, @agc. I accidentally provided only natural numbers, but the intention here is to implement line-internal sorting with various tools. Use whatever natural (sic) sorting method comes with that tool. If it handles numbers / bases in extended “classes” (scientific, etc), feel free to point those out.

Comment: Seeing some of the other comments: the delimiter is arbitrary, but would be used consistently in the input. Assume intelligence on the part of the data producer such that they wouldn’t use commas as the delimiter and in the data (for example, `4,325 comma 55 comma 42,430` would not occur, nor `1.5 period 4.2`).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With `gawk` ([**GNU** `awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)) for the [`asort()` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting-Functions.html):

```c
gawk -v SEP='*' '{ i=0; split($0, arr, SEP); len=asort(arr);
    while ( ++i<=len ){ printf("%s%s", i>1?SEP:"", arr[i]) }; 
        print "" 
}' infile
```

replace `*` as the field separator in `SEP='*'` with your *delimiter*.

---

---

You can also do with the following command in case of a single line ([because it's better leave it alone of using shell-loops for text-processing purposes](/q/169716/72456))

```
tr '.' '\n' <<<"$aline" | sort -n | paste -sd'.' -
```

replace *dots* `.` with your delimiter.
add `-u` to the `sort` command above to remove the duplicates.

**Notes:**
You may need to use `-g, --general-numeric-sort` option of `sort` instead of `-n, --numeric-sort` to handle any class of numbers (integer, float, scientific, Hexadecimal, etc).

```
$ aline='2e-18,6.01e-17,1.4,-4,0xB000,0xB001,23,-3.e+11'
$ tr ',' '\n' <<<"$aline" |sort -g | paste -sd',' -
-3.e+11,-4,2e-18,6.01e-17,1.4,23,0xB000,0xB001
```

In `awk` no need change, it still will handling those.

Answer (score 13):

Using `perl` there's an obvious version; split the data, sort it, join it back up again.

The delimiter needs to be listed twice (once in the `split` and once in the `join`)

eg for a `,`

```
perl -lpi -e '$_=join(",",sort {$a <=> $b} split(/,/))'
```

So

```
echo 1,100,330,42 | perl -lpi -e '$_=join(",",sort {$a <=> $b} split(/,/))'
1,42,100,330
```

Since the `split` is a regex, the character may need quoting:

```
echo 10.1.200.42 | perl -lpi -e '$_=join(".",sort {$a <=> $b} split(/\./))'
1.10.42.200
```

By using the `-a` and `-F` options, it's possible to remove the split. 
 With the `-p` loop, as before and set the results to `$_`, which will automatically print:

```
perl -F'/\./' -aple '$_=join(".", sort {$a <=> $b} @F)'
```

Comment: you can use the `-l` option instead of using `chomp`. That also adds back the newline upon printing. See also `-a` (with `-F`) for the splitting part.

Comment: With `-l` and `-F`, it's even nicer: `perl -F'/\./' -le 'print join(".", sort {$a <=> $b} @F)'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for the `-l` option; I'd missed that!

Comment: @muru I didn't use the `-F` flag originally because it doesn't work properly in all versions (eg your line in CentOS 7 - perl 5.16.3 - returns blank output, although it works fine on Debian 9).  But combined with `-p` it gives a slightly smaller result, so I added that as an alternative to the answer. showing how `-F` can be used.  Thanks!

Comment: @StephenHarris that's because newer versions of perl automatically adds `-a` and `-n` options when `-F` is used and `-n` when `-a` is used... so just change `-le` to `-lane`

Answer (score 7):

Using Python and a similar idea as in [Stephen Harris' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/436105/70524):

```
python3 -c 'import sys; c = sys.argv[1]; sys.stdout.writelines(map(lambda x: c.join(sorted(x.strip().split(c), key=int)) + "\n", sys.stdin))' <delmiter>
```

So something like:

```
$ cat foo
10.129.3.4
1.1.1.1
4.3.2.1
$ python3 -c 'import sys; c = sys.argv[1]; sys.stdout.writelines(map(lambda x: c.join(sorted(x.strip().split(c), key=int)) + "\n", sys.stdin))' . < foo
3.4.10.129
1.1.1.1
1.2.3.4
```

Sadly having to do the I/O manually makes this far less elegant than the Perl version.

Answer (score 5):

#### Using `sed` to sort octets of an IP address

`sed` does not have a built-in `sort` function, but if your data is sufficiently constrained in range (such as with IP addresses), you can generate a sed script that manually implements a simple [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). The basic mechanism is to look for adjacent numbers that are out-of-order. If the numbers are out of order, swap them.

The `sed` script itself contains two search-and-swap commands for each pair of out-of-order numbers: one for the first two pairs of octets (forcing a trailing delimiter to be present to mark the end of the third octet), and a second for the third pair of octets (end with EOL). If swaps occur, the program branches to the top of the script, looking for numbers that are out-of-order. Otherwise, it exits.

The generated script is, in part:

```
$ head -n 3 generated.sed
:top
s/255\.254\./254.255./g; s/255\.254$/254.255/
s/255\.253\./253.255./g; s/255\.253$/253.255/

# ... middle of the script omitted ...

$ tail -n 4 generated.sed
s/2\.1\./1.2./g; s/2\.1$/1.2/
s/2\.0\./0.2./g; s/2\.0$/0.2/
s/1\.0\./0.1./g; s/1\.0$/0.1/
ttop
```

This approach hard-codes the period as the delimiter, which has to be escaped, as otherwise it would be "special" to the regular expression syntax (allowing any character).

To generate such a sed script, this loop will do:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ':top'

for (( n = 255; n >= 0; n-- )); do
  for (( m = n - 1; m >= 0; m-- )); do
    printf '%s; %s\n' "s/$n\\.$m\\./$m.$n./g" "s/$n\\.$m\$/$m.$n/"
  done
done

echo 'ttop'
```

Redirect the output of that script to another file, say `sort-ips.sed`.

A sample run could then look like:

```
ip=$((RANDOM % 256)).$((RANDOM % 256)).$((RANDOM % 256)).$((RANDOM % 256))
printf '%s\n' "$ip" | sed -f sort-ips.sed
```

---

The following variation on the generating script uses the word boundary markers `\<` and `\>` to get rid of the need of the second substitution.  This also cuts down the generated script's size from 1.3 MB to just under 900 KB along with greatly reducing the run time of the `sed` itself (to about 50%-75% of the original, depending on what `sed` implementation is being used):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ':top'

for (( n = 255; n >= 0; --n )); do
  for (( m = n - 1; m >= 0; --m )); do
      printf '%s\n' "s/\\<$n\\>\\.\\<$m\\>/$m.$n/g"
  done
done

echo 'ttop'
```

Comment: An interesting idea, but it does seem to be over-complicating things a bit.

Comment: @Matt It's kinda the point. Sorting anything with `sed` is ridiculous, which is why it's an interesting challenge.

Answer (score 5):

#### Shell

Loading a higher level language takes time.
For a few lines, the shell itself may be a solution.
We can use the external command `sort`, and of the command `tr`. One is quite efficient in sorting lines and the other is effective to convert one delimiter to newlines:

```
#!/bin/bash
shsort(){
           while IFS='' read -r line; do
               echo "$line" | tr "$1" '\n' |
               sort -n   | paste -sd "$1" -
           done <<<"$2"
    }

shsort ' '    '10 50 23 42'
shsort '.'    '10.1.200.42'
shsort ','    '1,100,330,42'
shsort '|'    '400|500|404'
shsort ','    '3 b,2       x,45    f,*,8jk'
shsort '.'    '10.128.33.6
128.17.71.3
44.32.63.1'
```

This need bash because of the use of `<<<` only. If that is replaced with a here-doc, the solution is valid for posix.
This is able to sort fields with tabs, spaces or shell glob characters (`*`, `?`, `[`). Not newlines because each line is being sorted.

Change `<<<"$2"` to `<"$2"` to process filenames and call it like:

```
shsort '.'    infile
```

The delimiter is the same for the whole file. If that is a limitation, it could be improved on.

However a file with just 6000 lines takes 15 seconds to process. Truly, the shell is not the best tool to process files.

#### Awk

For more than a few lines (more than a few 10's) it is better to use a real programming language. An awk solution could be:

```
#!/bin/bash
awksort(){
           gawk -v del="$1" '{
               split($0, fields, del)
               l=asort(fields)
               for(i=1;i<=l;i++){
                   printf( "%s%s" , (i==0)?"":del , fields[i] )
               }
               printf "\n"
           }' <"$2"
         }

awksort '.'    infile
```

Which takes only 0.2 seconds for the same 6000 lines file mentioned above.

Understand that the `<"$2"` for files could be changed back to `<<<"$2"` for lines inside shell variables.

#### Perl

The fastest solution is perl.

```
#!/bin/bash
perlsort(){  perl -lp -e '$_=join("'"$1"'",sort {$a <=> $b} split(/['"$1"']/))' <<<"$2";   }

perlsort ' '    '10 50 23 42'
perlsort '.'    '10.1.200.42'
perlsort ','    '1,100,330,42'
perlsort '|'    '400|500|404'
perlsort ','    '3 b,2       x,45    f,*,8jk'
perlsort '.'    '10.128.33.6
128.17.71.3
44.32.63.1'
```

If you want to sort a file change `<<<"$a"` to simply `"$a"` and add `-i` to perl options to make the file edition "in place":

```
#!/bin/bash
perlsort(){  perl -lpi -e '$_=join("'"$1"'",sort {$a <=> $b} split(/['"$1"']/))' "$2"; }

perlsort '.' infile; exit
```

Answer (score 5):

Bash script:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

join_by(){ local IFS="$1"; shift; echo "$*"; }

IFS="$1" read -r -a tokens_array <<< "$2"
IFS=$'\n' sorted=($(sort -n <<<"${tokens_array[*]}"))
join_by "$1" "${sorted[@]}"
```

Example:

```
$ ./sort_delimited_string.sh "." "192.168.0.1"
0.1.168.192
```

Based on

- [Split string into an array in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10586153/3701431)
- [How to sort an array in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7442417/3701431)
- [Join elements of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1527049/3701431)

Answer (score 3):

Here some bash that guesses the delimiter by itself:

```
#!/bin/bash

delimiter="${1//[[:digit:]]/}"
if echo $delimiter | grep -q "^\(.\)\1\+$"
then
  delimiter="${delimiter:0:1}"
  if [[ -z $(echo $1 | grep "^\([0-9]\+"$delimiter"\([0-9]\+\)*\)\+$") ]]
  then
    echo "You seem to have empty fields between the delimiters."
    exit 1
  fi
  if [[ './\' == *$delimiter* ]]
  then
    n=$( echo $1 | sed "s/\\"$delimiter"/\\n/g" | sort -n | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -e "s/\\s/\\"$delimiter"/g")
  else
    n=$( echo $1 | sed "s/"$delimiter"/\\n/g" | sort -n | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -e "s/\\s/"$delimiter"/g")
  fi
  echo ${n%$delimiter}
  exit 0
else
  echo "The string does not consist of digits separated by one unique delimiter."
  exit 1
fi
```

It might not be very efficient nor clean but it works.

Use like `bash my_script.sh "00/00/18/29838/2"`.

Returns an error when the same delimiter is not used consistently or when two or more delimiters follow each other.

If the used delimiter is a special character then it is escaped (otherwise `sed` returns an error).

Comment: That inspired [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/436451/165517).

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on a misunderstanding of the Q., but in some cases it happens to be correct anyway.  If the input is entirely [natural numbers](https://oeis.org/A001477), and has only *one* delimiter per-line, (as with the sample data in the Q.), it works correctly.  It'll also handle files with lines that each have their own delimiter, which is a bit more than what was asked for.

This shell function `read`s from standard input, uses *POSIX parameter substitution* to find the specific delimiter on each line, (stored in `$d`), and uses `tr` to replace `$d` with a newline `\n` and `sort`s that line's data, then restores each line's original delimiters:

```
sdn() { while read x; do
            d="${x#${x%%[^0-9]*}}"   d="${d%%[0-9]*}"
            x=$(echo -n "$x" | tr "$d" '\n' | sort -g | tr '\n' "$d")
            echo ${x%?}
        done ; }
```

Applied to the data given in the *OP*:

```
printf "%s\n" "10 50 23 42" "10.1.200.42" "1,100,330,42" "400|500|404" | sdn
```

Output:

```
10 23 42 50
1.10.42.200
1,42,100,330
400|404|500
```

Comment: The delimiter in any line will be consistent; general solutions that allow the user to declare the delimiter are awesome, but answers may assume any delimiter that makes sense to them (single character and not present in the numeric data itself).

Answer (score 3):

For arbitrary delimiters:

```
perl -lne '
  @list = /\D+|\d+/g;
  @sorted = sort {$a <=> $b} grep /\d/, @list;
  for (@list) {$_ = shift@sorted if /\d/};
  print @list'
```

On an input like:

```
5,4,2,3
6|5,2|4
There are 10 numbers in those 3 lines
```

It gives:

```
2,3,4,5
2|4,5|6
There are 3 numbers in those 10 lines
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is an variation on [Jeff's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/436103/116858) in the sense that it generates a `sed` script that will do Bubble sort, but is sufficiently different to warrant its own answer.

The difference is that instead of generating O(n^2) basic regular expressions, this generates O(n) extended regular expressions.  The resulting script will be about 15 KB big.  The running time of the `sed` script is in fractions of a second (it takes a bit longer to generate the script).

It's restricted to sorting positive integers delimited by dots, but it's not limited to the size of the integers (just increase `255` in the main loop), or the number of integers. The delimiter may be changed by changing `delim='.'` in the code.

It's done my head in to get the regular expressions right, so I'll leave describing the details for another day.

```
#!/bin/bash

# This function creates a extended regular expression
# that matches a positive number less than the given parameter.
lt_pattern() {
    local n="$1"  # Our number.
    local -a res  # Our result, an array of regular expressions that we
                  # later join into a string.

    for (( i = 1; i < ${#n}; ++i )); do
        d=$(( ${n: -i:1} - 1 )) # The i:th digit of the number, from right to left, minus one.

        if (( d >= 0 )); then
            res+=( "$( printf '%d[0-%d][0-9]{%d}' "${n:0:-i}" "$d" "$(( i - 1 ))" )" )
        fi
    done

    d=${n:0:1} # The first digit of the number.
    if (( d > 1 )); then
        res+=( "$( printf '[1-%d][0-9]{%d}' "$(( d - 1 ))" "$(( ${#n} - 1 ))" )" )
    fi

    if (( n > 9 )); then
        # The number is 10 or larger.
        res+=( "$( printf '[0-9]{1,%d}' "$(( ${#n} - 1 ))" )" )
    fi

    if (( n == 1 )); then
        # The number is 1. The only thing smaller is zero.
        res+=( 0 )
    fi

    # Join our res array of expressions into a '|'-delimited string.
    ( IFS='|'; printf '%s\n' "${res[*]}" )
}

echo ':top'

delim='.'

for (( n = 255; n > 0; --n )); do
    printf 's/\\<%d\\>\\%s\\<(%s)\\>/\\1%s%d/g\n' \
        "$n" "$delim" "$( lt_pattern "$n" )" "$delim" "$n"
done

echo 'ttop'
```

The script will look something like this:

```
$ bash generator.sh >script.sed
$ head -n 5 script.sed
:top
s/\<255\>\.\<(25[0-4][0-9]{0}|2[0-4][0-9]{1}|[1-1][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\>/\1.255/g
s/\<254\>\.\<(25[0-3][0-9]{0}|2[0-4][0-9]{1}|[1-1][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\>/\1.254/g
s/\<253\>\.\<(25[0-2][0-9]{0}|2[0-4][0-9]{1}|[1-1][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\>/\1.253/g
s/\<252\>\.\<(25[0-1][0-9]{0}|2[0-4][0-9]{1}|[1-1][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\>/\1.252/g
$ tail -n 5 script.sed
s/\<4\>\.\<([1-3][0-9]{0})\>/\1.4/g
s/\<3\>\.\<([1-2][0-9]{0})\>/\1.3/g
s/\<2\>\.\<([1-1][0-9]{0})\>/\1.2/g
s/\<1\>\.\<(0)\>/\1.1/g
ttop
```

The idea behind the generated regular expressions is to pattern match for numbers that are less than each integer; those two numbers would be out-of-order, and so are swapped. The regular expressions are grouped into several OR options. Pay close attention to the ranges appended to each item, sometimes they are `{0}`, meaning the immediately-previous item is to be omitted from the searching.  The regex options, from left-to-right, match numbers that are smaller than the given number by:

- the ones place
- the tens place
- the hundreds place
- (continued as needed, for larger numbers)
- or by being smaller in magnitude (number of digits)

To spell out an example, take `101` (with additional spaces for readability):

```
s/ \<101\> \. \<(10[0-0][0-9]{0} | [0-9]{1,2})\> / \1.101 /g
```

Here, the first alternation allows the numbers 100 through 100; the second alternation allows 0 through 99.

Another example is `154`:

```
s/ \<154\> \. \<(15[0-3][0-9]{0} | 1[0-4][0-9]{1} | [0-9]{1,2})\> / \1.154 /g
```

Here the first option allows 150 through 153; the second allows 100 through 149, and the last allows 0 through 99.

Testing four times in a loop:

```
for test_run in {1..4}; do
    nums=$(( RANDOM%256 )).$(( RANDOM%256 )).$(( RANDOM%256 )).$(( RANDOM%256 ))
    printf 'nums=%s\n' "$nums"
    sed -E -f script.sed <<<"$nums"
done
```

Output:

```
nums=90.19.146.232
19.90.146.232
nums=8.226.70.154
8.70.154.226
nums=1.64.96.143
1.64.96.143
nums=67.6.203.56
6.56.67.203
```

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`:

```bsh
$ # -a to auto-split on whitespace, results in @F array
$ echo 'foo baz v22 aimed' | perl -lane 'print join " ", sort @F'
aimed baz foo v22
$ # {$a <=> $b} for numeric comparison, {$b <=> $a} will give descending order
$ echo '1,100,330,42' | perl -F, -lane 'print join ",", sort {$a <=> $b} @F'
1,42,100,330
```

With `ruby`, which is somewhat similar to `perl`

```bsh
$ # -a to auto-split on whitespace, results in $F array
$ # $F is sorted and then joined using the given string
$ echo 'foo baz v22 aimed' | ruby -lane 'print $F.sort * " "'
aimed baz foo v22

$ # (&:to_i) to convert string to integer
$ echo '1,100,330,42' | ruby -F, -lane 'print $F.sort_by(&:to_i) * ","'
1,42,100,330

$ echo '10.1.200.42' | ruby -F'\.' -lane 'print $F.sort_by(&:to_i) * "."'
1.10.42.200
```

Custom command and passing just the delimiter string(not regex). Will work if input has floating data too

```bsh
$ # by default join uses value of $,
$ sort_line(){ ruby -lne '$,=ENV["d"]; print $_.split($,).sort_by(&:to_f).join' ; }

$ s='103,14.5,30,24'
$ echo "$s" | d=',' sort_line
14.5,24,30,103
$ s='10.1.200.42'
$ echo "$s" | d='.' sort_line
1.10.42.200

$ # for file input
$ echo '123--87--23' > ip.txt
$ echo '3--12--435--8' >> ip.txt
$ d='--' sort_line <ip.txt
23--87--123
3--8--12--435
```

Custom command for `perl`

```bsh
$ sort_line(){ perl -lne '$d=$ENV{d}; print join $d, sort {$a <=> $b} split /\Q$d/' ; }
$ s='123^[]$87^[]$23'
$ echo "$s" | d='^[]$' sort_line 
23^[]$87^[]$123
```

Further reading - I already had this handy list of perl/ruby one-liners

- [perl - sorting](https://github.com/learnbyexample/Command-line-text-processing/blob/master/perl_the_swiss_knife.md#sorting)
- [ruby - sorting](https://github.com/learnbyexample/Command-line-text-processing/blob/master/ruby_one_liners.md#sorting)

Answer (score 0):

This should handle any non-digit (0-9) delimiter. Example:

```bsh
x='1!4!3!5!2'; delim=$(echo "$x" | tr -d 0-9 | cut -b1); echo "$x" | tr "$delim" '\n' | sort -g | tr '\n' "$delim" | sed "s/$delim$/\n/"
```

Output:

```
1!2!3!4!5
```

Answer (score -2):

**Splitting input into multiple lines**

Using `tr`, you can split the input using an arbitrary delimiter into multiple lines.

This input can then be run through `sort` (using `-n` if the input is numerical).

If you wish to retain the delimiter in the output, you can then use `tr` again to add back the delimiter.

e.g. using space as a delimiter

`cat input.txt | tr " " "\n" | sort -n | tr "\n" " "`

input: `1 2 4 1 4 32 18 3`
output: `1 1 2 3 4 4 18 32`

Comment: You may safely assume numeric items, and yes: the delimiter should be replaced.