# Summing rows in a new column using sed, awk and perl?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, perl

I have a file that contain numbers something like:

```
1 11 323
2 13 3
3 44 4
4 66 23
5 70 23
6 34 23
7 24 22
8 27 5
```

How can I sum the rows and output the results in a column, so the results are as follows:

```
1 11 323 335
2 13 3 18
3 44 4 51
4 66 23 93
5 70 23 98
6 34 23 63
7 24 22 53
8 27 5 40
```

I would like to see solutions in sed, awk, and perl

Comment: while sed's not normally used for addition, [it can be done](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36959/117549)

Answer (score 8):

Perl solution:

```
perl -MList::Util=sum -lane 'print "@F ", sum(@F)' < data.txt
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to output
- `-a` splits each input line on whitespace into the @F array
- [List::Util](http://p3rl.org/List::Util) provides the `sum` function so you don't have to sum the numbers yourself

In sed, arithmetic is nearly impossible to implement, but you can use sed to turn spaces into pluses and use that as a source for `bc` to get the sums, and paste the results with the input:

```
paste -d ' ' data.txt <(sed -r 's/ /+/g' data.txt | bc)
```

Comment: sed is not working. I get this message "Missing name for redirect."

Comment: @Shervan Are you sure you're using `bash`?

Answer (score 4):

Let's say that your data is saved in a file called data.txt.

```
cat data.txt
1 11 323
2 13 3
3 44 4
4 66 23
5 70 23
6 34 23
7 24 22
8 27 5
```

You can do it in `awk` as follows:

```
awk '{X=$0}{split(X,x)}{print X , x[1]+x[2]+x[3]}' data.txt
1 11 323 335
2 13 3 18
3 44 4 51
4 66 23 93
5 70 23 98
6 34 23 63
7 24 22 53
8 27 5 40
```

Or, per @RudiC's comment:

```
awk '{print $0, $1+$2+$3}' data.txt
```

Comment: Why not `awk '{print $0, $1+$2+$3}' file`?

Comment: how can I do it in sed pelae?

Comment: `sed` is a (stream) editor, not a calculator.

Comment: @RudiC but it can do addition: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36959/117549

Answer (score 4):

For an arbitrary number of columns, using `awk`:

```
$ awk '{ sum = 0; for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) sum += $i; $(NF + 1) = sum } 1' <file
1 11 323 335
2 13 3 18
3 44 4 51
4 66 23 93
5 70 23 98
6 34 23 63
7 24 22 53
8 27 5 40
```

`NF` is the number of fields (whitespace separated columns by default) in the current record (line by default).  By calculating `sum` in a loop and setting `$(NF + 1)` to the total, we add a new column at the end.  This new column is printed along with the others by the lone `1` at the end of the `awk` script (this may be replaced by `{ print }`).

---

`sed` is not really suited for doing any form of arithmetics.

Comment: Thank you! please how can I do it in sed?

Comment: @Shervan You can't.  `sed` does not support arithmetic operations.

Comment: @Shervan And when I say "you can't", I mean that you can, but it would be _extremely difficult_ as you would have to do so with the aid of regular expressions and the other text manipulating facilities that `sed` provides. It would be as difficult to do with `sed` as with an ordinary plain text editor that does not support arithmetic operations natively.

Comment: @Shervan See e.g. my solution to solving a sorting problem with `sed`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/436251/116858

Comment: @Kusalananda. he can do something like this `cat data | sed -e 's,$, + p,g' | dc`, no? or `cat data | sed -e 's/\ /+/g' | bc`

Comment: @Goro Yes, that would be using `sed` to generate a `dc`/`bc` script.  This is different from doing the actual calculation in `sed` though.

Comment: @Kusalananda. of course

Answer (score 0):

What about a pure bash solution ?

```
while read -r a b c; do
    echo $a $b $c $((a+b+c))
done < input
```

[Sample run](https://ideone.com/wWQD9O)