# Sorting elements of a CSV file

Tags: awk, sed, sort, csv

I have a csv file with seven numbers per line like this:

```
1083,20,28,42,23,10,43
1084,20,5,29,59,40,33
1085,39,50,21,12,40,55
1086,45,4,6,23,10,2
1087,36,46,28,32,3,20
```

I want to keep the first number in place (column 1) and  sort columns 2 to 7, making the file like

```
1083,10,20,23,28,42,43
1084,5,20,29,33,40,59
1085,12,21,39,40,50,55
1086,2,4,6,10,45,23
1087,3,20,28,32,36,46
```

How can I do that with `awk`, `sed` or whatever?

Thanks

Comment: Similar idea: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/436102/117549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is you have files with MAC line endings (\r) whereas the commands you are running are assuming Unix line endings (\n).

Use `Perl`:

```
$ perl -l015 -F, -0015 -pae '$_ = join ",", shift @F, sort { $a <=> $b } @F' input.csv
```

**Options:**

- `-l` sets `ORS` to `\r` = octal 15.
- `-0` sets `RS` to `\r` = octal 15.
- `-p` will loop thru your csv file on a per record basis. A record is split from the input file by the RS, which is `\r` as set by the `-0` option.
- `-F` will set the field separator to comma for each record as it is read.
- `-a` will split each record as it is being read into fields and stored in array `@F`.
- Note: the order of supplying the options is important.

So the output that you will get shall also have MAC line endings. That is why you are NOT seeing your expected output, rather all your output records appear squashed into a single line based on all the solutions given here.

Comment: Now we are talking. Your answer is perfect and is the only one that works for me and the only one that fits what I was saying. Cannot upvote you enough. THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`:

```
perl -F, -lape '$_ = join ",", shift @F, sort {$a <=> $b} @F' < input.csv
```

With  GNU `awk`:

```
gawk -F, '
  {
    split($0, a)
    printf "%s", a[1]
    delete a[1]
    n = asort(a)
    for (i = 1; i <= n ; i++) printf "%s", FS a[i]
    print ""
  }' < input.csv
```

Or using the `join.awk` library (thanks @WeijunZhou)

```
gawk -i join -F, -v OFS=, '
  {
    split($0, a)
    first = a[1]
    delete a[1]
    n = asort(a)
    print first, join(a, 1, n, OFS)
  }'
```

Comment: thanks but that is destroying part of the file. Some lines end like this `,47,50,5519`

Comment: @SpaceDog, sounds like your file has CRLF MS-DOS line endings, convert it to Unix first (using `dos2unix` for instance) or insert a `s/\r$//;` at the start of the `perl` code above.

Comment: I don't gave gawk. I am no macOS. Your perl command is not working even on the unix converted file.

Comment: In your `gawk` code, `-F,` is not needed. Assuming nonneg numbers, with recent `gawk`, `gawk -F, '@include "join";{split($0,a,",");a[1]=0;asort(a);print $1","join(a,2,7,",")}'`

Comment: @WeijunZhou - unfortunately I do not have gawk on macOS.

Comment: Then you need to implement `asort` yourself. Using `perl` is much simpler but I am not familiar with it.

Comment: @SpaceDog, you can install it using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

Answer (score -2):

For simple `csv` without quoting, try this:

```
while IFS= read -r l; do
    col1=$(printf '%s' "$l" | cut -d, -f1)
    printf '%s,' "$col1"
    printf '%s' "$l" | cut -d, -f2- | grep -o "[0-9]*" | sort -n | paste -sd,
done < file
```

Comment: file is completely destroyed, like this... 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,...

Comment: Works fine for me on your given test file.

Comment: sorry, not working for me at all.

Comment: @SpaceDog, what does `file your-file.csv` return?

Comment: I have two versions of the file, one unix and one windows. [Here](https://ufile.io/5angu) is the unix version of the file if you want to test.

Comment: for me it works just as I think it should using your "unix" version of the file ... Don't know what you're doing. And don't know why these downvotes ...

Comment: About one of the downvotes, see [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716), [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346), [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803) (also the part about the first argument of `printf` being the _format_).

Comment: thanks, I changed the printf and variables not quoted part ...

Answer (score -3):

Tried with below method combination of awk and sed

j=`awk '{print NR}' filename | sort -nr| sed -n '1p'`

```
for ((i=1;i<=$j;i++)); do k=`awk -F "," -v  i="$i" 'NR==i {print $1}' i.txt` ;echo $k;awk -F "," -v i="$i" 'NR==i {$1=" ";print $0}' i.txt| sed -r "s/^\s+//g"| perl -pne "s/ /\n/g"| sort -n| perl -pne "s/\n/ /g";echo " "| sed "s/.*/&\n/g";done|sed '/^$/d'| sed "N;s/\n/ /g"| sed "s/ /,/g"| sed "s/\,*$//g"
```

output

```
1083,10,20,23,28,42,43
1084,5,20,29,33,40,59
1085,12,21,39,40,50,55
1086,2,4,6,10,23,45
1087,3,20,28,32,36,46
```

Comment: I do not even know how to use this... You have a variable declared on the first line (?) then a second line... ???